# Centered fixed width layout with 100% padding on one side only

Tags: css

I really like Elliot Jay Stock's new blog's layout:

http://elliotjaystocks.com/

As you can see, the left part of the content column stretches out all the way to the edge. He achieves this effect by using percentages to make sure the column fills 100% of the window.

But how could you achieve the same effect with a fixed width central column?

Comment: Have you tried anything out already?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it by "faking" the padding. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jYHc9/2/.